# Improve Speed of Script with Indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following script that used to be ok, but since our user base has now expanded to almost a million members, the script is now very sluggish.  I want to improve it and need expert assistance to make this faster, with either coding changes, create indexes, or both.  Here is the code:

```
IF @MODE = 'CREATEREQUEST'
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FriendRequest WHERE FromMemberID = @FromMemberID AND ToMemberID = @ToMemberID) 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MemberConnection WHERE MemberID = @FromMemberID AND ConnMemberID = @ToMemberID)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MemberConnection WHERE MemberID = @ToMemberID AND ConnMemberID = @FromMemberID)

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO FriendRequest (
                FromMemberID,
                ToMemberID,
                RequestMsg,
                OnHold)
            VALUES (
                @FromMemberID,
                @ToMemberID,
                @RequestMsg,
                @OnHold)
        END
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Member SET FriendRequestCount = (FriendRequestCount + 1) WHERE MemberID = @ToMemberID
        END
END
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Have you profiled this code to identify the statement(s) running slowly, and what is the execution plan?

Comment: It's impossible to see what improvements can be made if you don't include **table definition, execution plan, and any current indexes**.

Comment: Also tell us how many rows are in each of these tables, and what "very sluggish" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to view the indexes on a table.  If, for example, your FriendRequest table has a PK on FriendRequestID, you will be able to see that you have a clustered index on that field.  You can have only one clustered index per table, and the table records are stored in that order.

You might want to try adding non-clustered indexes to your foreign key fields.  You could use the New Index wizard, or else syntax like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FromMemberID] ON [dbo].[FriendRequest] (FromMemberID)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ToMemberID] ON [dbo].[FriendRequest] (ToMemberID)
```

But you should be aware that indexing will generally slow down the INSERT and UPDATE operations you showed in your code.  It will generally tend to speed up the SELECT queries that can use the indexed fields (see [Execution Plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

You can try the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) to get an idea of some possible indexes and their effect on your application's workload.

Indexing is a large subject and you may wish to take it a small step at a time.

Comment: FYI: A PK doesn't necessarily have to be clustered. Please don't spread the myth that these two things are always together.